# "uninitialized constant Sass::Script (NameError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I had first to change my Gemfile from (I deleted the comments to make the text shorter):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

to:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails',                '4.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.1'
gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end
```

now when I try to run the rails server with `rails server -b $IP -p $PORT` I get following error message:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:11:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Sass::Script (NameError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello_app/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello_app/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello_app/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello_app/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I tried the running the servers before changing the Gemfile, and it works, so it must be because of the new changes. Also I'm aware in the error it says `ruby-2.1.5`, and in my Gemfile I put 4.2.0 but I have no clue how to change this, or if this is even the problem? i tried to add `ruby '2.1.5'` under the source line, nothing changed. Also I changed `'rails', '4.2.0'` to 2.1.5 but then the update failed telling me `Could not find gem 'rails (= 2.1.5) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As said here:

https://github.com/josh/sprockets-es6/issues/15

Use `sass-rails v 5.0.2+`. This should solve your issue. So in the gem file change:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.3'
```

or

```
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.2'
```

**Update:**

As the link is down now so this issue is actually with the gem version `5.0.1` so just run:

```
bundle update sass-rails
```

which ultimately updates you `saas-rails` gem to the latest one. Or you can enter the version in your gemfile as specified above.

Comment: it does work, thanks. the author of the book recommends to use the same settings he does, since one might get different results during the tutorial with different versions, so i'm wondeirng if there is any other way? (btw the `sass-rails v 5.0.2+` command did not work, telling me `command not found`)

Comment: no actually that is a bug in the gem so you need to use the new version and that should not effect the results.

Comment: you can always accept the answers to your question by clicking the correct tick symbol so if any other user faces the same issue this might help him too

Comment: I am facing the issue even after making the version to 5.0.4. Any help?

Comment: Thank you. minor version but solves all. sass-rails 5.0.1 is mentioned in https://www.railstutorial.org

Comment: `sprockets` once
[required](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/v2.12.5/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb#L1)
[`sass`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/v3.0.0.beta.5/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb).
That allowed `sass-rails` to not
[do](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/blob/v5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb#L1)
[so](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/blob/v5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb#L6).

Comment: ...Now, `rails-4.2.x` depends on the
[latest](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4d157ea8c1)
version of
[`sprockets-rails`](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6d02b75b2b).
Which means updating `rails-4.2.x` effectively switches to the latest `sprockets`.
If that was `sprockets` `2.x -> 3.x` kind of change, you've most likely got
yourself broken `rails`.
That was eventually
[fixed](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/pull/319/files#diff-b05bb709e4e309b71a9801cb6ee24517R1)
in
[`sass-rails-5.0.2`](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/blob/v5.0.2/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb#L1)

Answer (score 1):

`bundle update sass-rails` did the trick for me when upgrading to Rails 4.2.2.

Comment: I did the same. Now `bundle install` gives me `Using sass-rails 5.0.4` but I am still facing the error. Any help?