# Error in rake db:create in new rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, rake

I get the following error:

rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Sass::Script
/home/nikhil/Nurture/careerpal-back/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nikhil/Nurture/careerpal-back/Rakefile:4:in`'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Gemfile is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

I have already updated all gems to their latest versions by running `bundle update` and changed the sass-rails gem to a specific version. It still won't run

Gemfile.lock has these lines

```
sass (3.4.21)
sass-rails (5.0.4)
  railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
  sass (~> 3.1)
  sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
  sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
  tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
```

But running `bundle install` gives me this:

```
Using sass 3.4.21
Using sass-rails 5.0.4
```

EDIT:
I had earlier created a api only rails project with 4.2.4. It ran alright.

Help appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: May be duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716284/uninitialized-constant-sassscript-nameerror

Comment: Looked at it. Did not fix the issue

Comment: Did you try: "Turns out I needed the `sass` gem to be explicitly required before `sass-rails` and `sprockets`." https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/315

Comment: Yeah did that. included `sass` gem before `sass-rails`and ran `bundle install`. But `rake db:create` again gave the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply reinstalled ruby+rails and things were alright.

I deleted the ~/.rbenv folder and ran `sudo apt-get purge ruby`

Then installed ruby and rails using [Official Page](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/15.10).

**Importantly, once I created a new project I was prompted to install another gem to resolve some dependency `gem install rdoc-data`**

Answer (score 0):

Run step by step, at first:

```
gem install bundler
```

Then

```
bundle install
```

& Then

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

For learn [bundler](http://bundler.io/), Create rails [project](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-rails-project)

Hope will help you

Comment: Still the same. Here is a list of commands that I ran.
`rails new testProject`, `cd testProject`, `gem install bundler`
on which I got error
Then `bundle install` ran alright. `bundle exec db:create` gave the same error.

Comment: Not `bundle exec db:create` should `bundle exec rake db:migrate` & create project  without test word

Comment: sry that was a typo. I ran `bundle exec rake db:migrate` else it would have given rake error. However reinstalling the entire ruby on rails framework did fix the issue. The problem was only when I updated to new version.