# Failed to push some refs while pushing Rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am completely new to Ruby on Rails. I was trying to make a "Hello, world!" web app following Hartl's tutorial, but I couldn't get the app to deploy on Heroku. I have added the files to git, and committed them as well. Also, the app runs fine on my local machine.

Here is what I get when I run `git push heroku master`:-

```
[xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx]: ~/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/hello_app$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 70, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (59/59), done.
Writing objects: 100% (70/70), 16.77 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 70 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rake 11.1.2
remote:        Installing minitest 5.8.4
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.0.0
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0221
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.3
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.1
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Installing pg 0.17.1 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.22
remote:        Installing tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.2
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.7.2 with native extensions
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.0
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 2.5.3
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.5.2
remote:        Installing rails_12factor 0.0.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.0
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.0
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.4
remote:        Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.2.0
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.2.3
remote:        Installing activejob 4.2.0
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.2.0
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing actionview 4.2.0
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.2.0
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 3.0.4
remote:        Installing railties 4.2.0
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.2.0
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.0.3
remote:        Installing rails 4.2.0
remote:        Installing sass-rails 5.0.1
remote:        Installing turbolinks 2.3.0
remote:        Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 53 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Post-install message from rdoc:
remote:        Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
remote:        <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
remote:        = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
remote:        Bundle completed (24.40s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sass-rails'.
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/Rakefile:4:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
remote:  !     NameError: uninitialized constant Sass::Script
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/Rakefile:4:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
remote:  !
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:102:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
remote: ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote: and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote: rake aborted!
remote: Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sass-rails'.
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/Rakefile:4:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
remote: NameError: uninitialized constant Sass::Script
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/Rakefile:4:in `require'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
remote: /tmp/build_3aeecd69679ac941d5b570bfb2ae7cdc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
remote: vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:746:in `rake'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:131:in `log'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:70:in `run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:767:in `allow_git'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:98:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:88:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:49:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:47:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:38:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:37:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in `block in compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in `compile'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:16:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/base.rb:131:in `log'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:15:in `block in <main>'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:     from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/ruby/bin/compile:11:in `<main>'
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to enigmatic-sea-29941.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/enigmatic-sea-29941.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/enigmatic-sea-29941.git'
```

I am using gem versions consistent with the tutorial. This is my Gemfile:-

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.1'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '2.5.3'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '2.3.0'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '2.2.3'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug','3.4.0'

  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3','1.3.9'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring', '1.1.3'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Can someone help me with out with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said here on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716284/uninitialized-constant-sassscript-nameerror)

Just run: `bundle update sass-rails`

Which ultimately updates you sass-rails gem to the latest one. Or you can enter the version in your gemfile upper than 5.0.1.

It seems there is a problem with 5.0.1 sass-rails version

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly now. :) May I ask how you deduced it was an issue with sass-rails? I couldn't figure it out from the error.

Comment: In your git push logs, line 89, there is this line : `Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sass-rails'.` which clearly puts sass-rails in the light.